# Igualdade de campos Data entre tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados

Numa tabela tenho um campo  Data A no formato 'dd.mm.aaaa'.
Em outra, campo data B no formato aaaammdd

Quero pesquisar todos os campos onde a data A é igual a B

Comment: As colunas são de que tipo? `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados? Sql Server, Mysql, Oracle ?

Comment: Um campo é DATA(DD.MM.AAA) e o outro numérico(AAAAMMDD).

Comment: o banco de dados é SQL

Comment: Julio, todos esses bancos de dados são SQL. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Firebird, MariaDB, HSQL, Derby, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc. Com qual deles você está lidando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TabelaA A, TabelaB B
WHERE B.datab = YEAR(A.dataa) * 10000 + MONTH(A.dataa) * 100 + DAY(A.dataa)
```

Considerando que os campos que você quer sejam `dataa` da tabela `TabelaA` e `datab` da tabela `TabelaB`.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Julio Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não te restar mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no "✅" aqui do lado, o que também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se por outro lado, ainda não estiver satisfeito, deixe um comentário e vamos esclarecer.